# Changing the colour of median and mean in ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, median, violin-plot

Please ignore the random dots all over the graph - this is just a quick reproducible example to show what I mean:

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_violin(alpha = 0.5) +
  stat_summary(aes(shape="mean",group=1),fun = "mean",
               size = 2, geom = "point", color = "black") +
  stat_summary(aes(shape = "median", group = 2), fun = "median",
               size = 2, geom = "point", color = "red") +
  labs(x = "Sepal Length", y = "Sepal Width",
       shape = "Shape", colour = "Species") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: Iris Graph]

How do I:

a). Change the legend so that there is no red dot in the middle of the box for each categorical variable?
b). Change the colour of the "shape" legend so that "mean" is black and "median" is red?

I have Googled for over an hour and cannot find the answer, so help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `override.aes` argument to legend guides that you can use to explicitly set an aesthetic for a key.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_violin(alpha = 0.5) +
  stat_summary(aes(shape="mean",group=1),fun = "mean",
               size = 2, geom = "point", color = "black") +
  stat_summary(aes(shape = "median", group = 2), fun = "median",
               size = 2, geom = "point", color = "red") +
  labs(x = "Sepal Length", y = "Sepal Width",
       shape = "Shape", colour = "Species") +
  guides(
    shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = c("black", "red"))),
    fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA))
  ) +
  theme_classic() 
#> Warning: position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals
```

[image]